# Creating a new array combining two existing objects through iteration with condition in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a main object consisting of two main properties, `data` which contains messages and `included` which contains the senders of the messages. I want to create a new Array called `messages` which will contain all the values of both objects but in a way that every object inside this array will consist of the data values adding the correct sender as property to each of them.

I am able to separate the main object to two different ones, one containing the data and the other containing the senders.

```
if (jsonAPI.data) {
    $.each(jsonAPI.data, function(index, value) {
        dataObj[index] = value;
    });
}

if (jsonAPI.included) {
    $.each(jsonAPI.included, function(index, value) {
        senders[value.id] = value;
    });
}
```

I guess I have to make an iteration for every value of the dataObj and check if the `relationships.sender.data.id` is equal to `senders.id` then add the new property to dataObj, but I don't know how to write it.

What I say can be more clear in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mosmic/f2dzduse/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f2dzduse/5/

```
var jsonAPI = {<snip>};

var dataObj = {};

if (jsonAPI.data) {
    $.each(jsonAPI.data, function(index, value) {
        dataObj[index] = value;
    });
}

$.each(dataObj, function(index, value) {
    //Prevent error if there is no sender data in included
    if(jsonAPI.included.length - 1 >= index) {
        //check if ids are equal
        if(value.relationships.sender.data.id == jsonAPI.included[index].id) {
            value.sender = jsonAPI.included[index];
        }
    }
});

console.log(dataObj);
```

This code assumes that `jsonAPI.data.relationships.sender.data.id` and `jsonAPI.included.id` are both in the same order!
If this is not always the case let me know and I'll rewrite the code to loop trough each `jsonAPI.data` and then loop trough `jsonAPI.include` to check for an equal id. This code will be slower since it will loop a total of `jsonAPI.data.length X jsonAPI.include` times.

Here's the updated code: https://jsfiddle.net/f2dzduse/6/

```
var jsonAPI = {<snip>};

var dataObj = [];

$.each(jsonAPI.data, function(x, data) {
    dataObj[x] = data;
    $.each(jsonAPI.included, function(y, included) {
        if(data.relationships.sender.data.id == included.id) {
            dataObj[x].sender = included;
        }
    });
});

console.log(dataObj);
```

Comment: I just checked the result. The sender is added only in the first two objects of the dataObj. Also order is not always the same.